# What is this sorting algorithm called?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
int max(int[] a, int m)
{
    int n = a.length;
    int t = a[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n-m; i++)
        if(a[i]>t) t = a[i];
    return t;
}

int[] unknownSort(int[] a)
{
    int n = a.length;
    for(int i=n-1,j=0; i>0; i--,j++)
        a[i] = max(a,j);

    return a;
}
```

It is much faster than bubble sort, but a little slower than insertion sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a sorting algorithm, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a clumsy implementation of selection sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Answer (score 0):

It will be a [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) if you write it correctly. Your algrorithm will just corrupt the data in the array.